# Something wrong with hands armature orientation/offsets when retargeting animation

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, rigify

I have human model generated with [Human Generator](https://blendermarket.com/products/humgen3d) addon. Next I import bvh I recorded on [Deepmotion](https://deepmotion.com) and retargeting its bones to my model bones with awesome [Renim Node](https://anasrar.gumroad.com/l/renim) addon. And here is the problem, retargeting is good, except hands part. You can see on the screen it's not even intersection, hands bones of the model clearly don't follow the bvh armature. I've tried set offsets inside Renim bone nodes, but it's impossible to get something good this way. I've tried it on both metarig and rigify, all the same, all good, hands are bad. Rotation on both human and armature is quaternion. Maybe someone faced same problem and can point me to the solution?[image]

Comment: Example with rigify https://imgur.com/a/ZGFe2OB

Answer (score 1):

I just got rid of bvh import, got fbx from deepmotion then did all bones retargeting as I did before and achieve the exact thing I wanted. So, someone who is strangling with similar behavior and use bvh, try avoid bvh and use fbx instead if you have such an option.